# Why is the definite article used in "the peace"?

Tags: definite-articles

I have difficulty wrapping my head around the use of the definite article *the* just before *peace*, in its first appearance, in the last in the following sentences.

> Noisy children skateboarding on the streets. Couples arguing in their
> homes. People gathered on the sidewalk, gossiping for long hours. Some
> people would describe these activities as noise pollution. A new
> website in Japan has put perpetrators on a map, spurring debate about
> those who disturb **the** peace.

This is the very first sentences of a news article, so there is no possibility that *peace* or any other related word has showed up beforehand.

Theoretically, *the peace* is supposed to mean the quiet and calm that would exist if there were no such noise pollution as mentioned in the sentence right before.

Nonetheless, the use of *the* in front of *peace* seems strange to me, compared with the sentence where *peace* stands alone with no definite article at all. I cannot comprehend the rationale behind the use of *the* here.

I know the definite article can be used when the noun is implied in or connected with something else that appears beforehand. (For example: I wanted to buy a new coat. But **the** sleeves were too long.) But I have no idea whether such implied usage applies to the use of *the* before *peace* here.

Which is more natural for native speakers with or without *the* in this particular case? Could you provide any reasoning or explanation?

Comment: The collocation *a disturbance of **the** peace* goes back [***at least 400 years***](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Countrey_Iustice_Conteyning_the_Prac/DxxlAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22disturbance+of+the+peace%22&pg=PA195&printsec=frontcover) in English. But it's really just a "frozen form" usage, that probably won't tell you anything about how English works today (apart from reminding us of the fact that *sometimes* we hang on to constructions that no longer reflect normal syntax - especially in the context of ***legal*** terminology).

Comment: From the full OED, ***Clerk of the Peace***  *an officer who prepares indictments and keeps a record of proceedings at **sessions of the peace***. First citation 1689. Someone else can find out what "sessions of the peace" were.

Comment: Here, *the peace* in *disturb the peace* is an idiomatic phrase, kind of like *the sidewalk* in *gathered on the sidewalk*.  We haven't specified which sidewalk we're talking about here, either. But for most nouns, we couldn't use *the*; for example, we wouldn't say *couples arguing in the house* without having specified which house.

Comment: I first thought "disturb the peace" was not an idiomatic expression because it makes sense literally. But thanks to the insightful suggestions, I now understand the phrase as idiomatic and thus the use of "the." Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that 'idiomatic' means 'regularly used and accepted by native speakers' in its default sense, not 'of the nature of, or being, an idiom' where an 'idiom' is a fixed phrase with unusual use of a word sense, unusual grammar, or both.

Comment: It’s the same reason you put *the* in front of “quiet and calm”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The peace* is a variant of *the King's peace* and that is indeed something definite: the peace (i.e. general orderliness) that normally prevails in the particular society under discussion, and is maintained (ultimately) by its king (somebody definite). That peace is something different from the peace that may prevail in another country, under a different sovereign. If one wants to understand the role of *the* in the generalised version of the phrase (*the peace*), one should think of it as, analogously, standing for the general orderliness that characterises the particular, politically organised, society that is under discsussion.

Comment: Since 'sour the atmosphere' is also idiomatic, and there is no corresponding 'the King's atmosphere', this needs justifying.

Answer (score 1):

*The peace* here is used in broadly the same way as one would talk of "the civil settlement" or "the social order".

Legally, one also historically encounters the notion of *the King's peace*, and of a disturbance or breach of it. Again, disturbing the King's peace doesn't necessarily mean causing a literal disturbance to the King personally, but disturbing the condition of peacefulness that his rule and authority (and system of justice) has brought to a place.

In the context it's used in the quotation in the question, to describe noise pollution, the usage is hyperbolic. One does not disturb "*the* peace" merely by emitting noise, there must be disorder, upset, or commotion of a kind that would cause a person to fear violence or property damage. The legal term for mere noise pollution would be "causing public nuisance".

A similar but more appropriate phrasing in the context of the quotation, would be to refer to "disturbing *the peace and quiet* of the neighbourhood", with "peace and quiet" being an idiom that means freedom from bother or noise of a general kind.

Answer (score 0):

Noise pollution may be an annoying but insufficient reason to involve the Police/Authorities. On the other hand, the term ‘Disturbance of the Peace’ covers the wording for an actual offence which does involve the Police (UK)

“**Disturbing the peace**” (also known as Breach of the Peace) is **an offence**, part of disorderly conduct crimes or public order offences for which penalties and imprisonment are issued. https://www.defencesolicitorslondon.co.uk/disturbing-the-peace-solicitors-london

The information given has the word ‘**perpetrator**’ and the term ‘**disturb the peace**,’ probably, to give a quasi-official/authoratitive impression to the reader. This may in turn cause the potential ‘perpetrators’ to be more considerate.

For instance. It could have read, more informally:

- A new website in Japan has put noisy troublemakers on a map, spurring
  debate about those who cause **the** disturbance.